# How to set the background of clicked or selected label on y axis gantt chart Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

I want to highlight the selected Y-axis label in Gantt charts. Also is there any way through which we can give some background color to the y-axis title?

yAxis: {
className: "highcharts-color-0",
uniqueNames: true,
title: {
text: "Data"
},
labels: {
events: {
click: function () {
alert("hellowww");
var chart = this,
series = chart.series,
plotLeft = chart.plotLeft,
plotTop = chart.plotTop,
plotWidth = chart.plotWidth;
if (chart.myBackground) {
chart.myBackground.destroy();
}

```
      chart.myBackground = chart.renderer
        .rect(10, plotTop, 500, 30, 1)
        .attr({
          "stroke-width": 2,
          stroke: "red",
          fill: "yellow",
          opacity: 0.5,
          zIndex: -1
        })
        .add();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t70h.png)

link to code pen https://codepen.io/mehrotrarohit07/pen/PoKxvQp?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this approach:

```
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          const chart = this.chart;
          const axis = this.axis;
          const labelPos = this.pos;
          const tick = axis.ticks[labelPos]
          const x = chart.marginRight;
          const width = tick.slotWidth;
          const height = axis.height / (axis.tickPositions.length);
          const y = axis.top + labelPos * height;

          chart.renderer
            .rect(x, y, tick.slotWidth, height)
            .attr({
              fill: 'yellow',
              zIndex: 0
            })
            .add();
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I hope that everything is clear from the code - in case of any doubts feel free to ask.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qyj327Lx/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Hi, @Sebastian Wędzel Thanks for the code it works like charm. Just a single doubt can we change the color of labels also when they are highlighted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RohitMehrotra I think that you can attach the HTML event to the yAxis label element to achieve it, check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ygb9rwe/